# how can i create a facebook like chat functionality on rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I am working on a rails app and i want to add a chat functionality just like facebook. does anyone know how i can go about it. i am kinda new to rails so the task is quit difficult form me to accomplish

Comment: https://pusher.com/tutorials/realtime_chat_widget#/lang=rb does the trick

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Messaging is a very difficult thing to do. I would stay away from it if you're new to Rails or web programming in general.

Otherwise, if you're up for a challenge, check out what I've answered on [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9383482/instant-messenger-implementation-for-rails/9384221#comment11854620_9384221)